# Promise chaining the correct way

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have a form where if users enter a number plate I want to look up the data and set a Vue data property before submitting the data.

I have a method to achieve this:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the carbon emissions for a given journey based on the distance 
 * as well as the given license plate (if any)
 */
retrieveCarbonEmissions: function() {
    return axios.get(`/api/expenses/dvla/${this.vehicle_registration}`)
        .then(response => {
            this.carbon_emissions = (response.data.co2emission * this.miles).toFixed(2);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // console.log(error.response);
            
            this.$swal({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Please enter a valid registration number in the "Car Registration" field.',
            });
        })
}
```

I am using `return` so that the Promise is returned so that I can use it in method chaining like so:

```
/**
 * Submit the given expense, if there is a number plate we'll try to get the CO2 emissions.
 * 
 */
submitExpense: function(){
    this.loader = this.$loading.show({
        container: this.fullPage ? null : this.$refs.editPersonalExpenseFormContainer
    });

    if(this.vehicle_registration){
        this.retrieveCarbonEmissions()
            .then((response) => {
                this.saveExpense();
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    } else{
        this.saveExpense();
    }
},
```

However, the inner method will run after the promise is resolved, irrespective of whether it fails.

How do I say do this and then do that, but if it fails just stop doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the `.catch()` in `retrieveCarbonEmissions`. When the promise -- on which this `.catch()`  is chained -- rejects, then its callback determines the resolution of the promise that `.catch()` (and thus `retrieveCarbonEmissions`) returns. In your case, it returns `undefined` and that means that returned promise is *fulfulled*, not *rejected*.

To make it reject, rethrow the error by adding a `throw error;` in that `catch` callback.

Comment: Hi, so in this way all the "child" methods should just pass the error up?

Comment: It really depends how you want it to behave. It is fine to not rethrow the error, but then you shouldn't expect the promise to reject. Be aware that every `then` and `catch` method call return a *new* promise, and if their callbacks are executed, these define how *that* particular promise will resolve.

Comment: I see, so in a way it's good practise to properly resolve all of your Promises rather than just putting a catch in and not doing much with it?

Comment: It depends on what you want. Sometimes you'll want to have a `.catch()` that returns a resolved promise instead of a rejected one. For instance when you consider that the callback function has done all that is needed to deal with an error and the overall process should continue without further issues. Other times you want a `.catch()` to deal with an error but keep the error state alive so that any further processing is aware that an error occurred that still needs special treatment.